# CocoaLumberjack/DDFileLogger.h' file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoalumberjack

i'm new in swift. I tried to run a project, but i got an error "CocoaLumberjack/DDFileLogger.h not found". I installed package through SPM and it installed perfectly fine, but when i try to import this, it keeps giving me an error. My xcode version is 13.0 and i'm working on mac big sur, could it be a problem with version or with m1?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in swift, you need to

```
import CocoaLumberjackSwift
```

see: [CocoaLumberjack README](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack#swift-usage)